# Adding existing method to WCF Service but no data returned

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I've added an existing method to a web service (that I did not write).

I can bring the method into Soap UI by performing and update on the service.

I can run the method in SOAP UI and debug it and clearly see my method is pulling the data I want, processing it correctly but I am getting nothing back in Soap UI and my debugger terminates at that point.

Its worth nothing I build this method from an existing working method that returns data just fine. I imagine I am just missing some minor configuration some ware.

Things I have done,

1) Added the new method to the operation contract

2) Added all the necessary logic for processing the data.

I can furnish any code/configs but I just don't know what exactly is needed to troubleshoot this as I am attempting to add this off existing code. I'm generally not a vague with the details but I'm in the process of educating myself at the same time as well as trudging through some existing documentation I have found online.

The service is intended to return a class. We define a DTO and paste the results from a SQL query into our DTO. We then do some integrity checking on the DTO and test for failure or success. We then add the DTO to a container object named CustomResult based on success or failure and return the CustomResult. The CustomResult class should not need any modifying (famous last words). I did however create a new DTO class which I can add to my original post

DTO Class

```
namespace Custom.Company.Services
{
  [DataContract]
  public class TimeUnitDto
  {
    [DataMember]
    public string Calendar { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long AverageHour { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long AverageDay { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long AverageWeek { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long AverageMonth { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long AverageYear { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long LookupRefreshInd { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Did you update the service reference or generate a new proxy?

Comment: My Service Reference folders are empty. I believe this is because the service is written on the Server Side. I don't have a client application that needs to know about this (yet). I'll keep looking.

Comment: It can be a serialization issue. Is this new method returns a class or a primitive type? If is a class, is it marked for serialization (DataContract/DataMember attributes)?

Comment: It returns a class. We define a DTO and paste the results from a SQL query into our DTO. We then do some integrity checking on the DTO and test for failure or success. We then add the DTO to a container object named 'CustomResult' based on success or failure and return the CustomResult. The CustomResult class should not need any modifying (famous last words). Mainly because its used everyware else in our services. I did however create a new DTO class which I can add to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

All, I figured it out. Unfortunately the answer is propriety to what I am doing but basically we the DTO to our CustomResult Class.

I copy/pasted the code from another service we use since the functionality was similar. I forgot to replace of the 'Status' assignments to the new status I created for this dto.

It was trying to place it in a Status object that the data is not going to recognize. Thanks to everyone who looked into this for me.